# is Android Email Client support pop protocols

Tags: android, email

is Android Email Client supported pop protocols.

Thanks.

Comment: 15 questions and no accepts == fail

Comment: I'm not sure if Stackoverflow is the right place for such a question. Maybe you should read the FAQ to get a better undestanding of what kind of question Stackoverflow is made for.

Comment: belongs on http://www.forceclose.com/

Comment: This isn't a programming question at all.

Comment: @kusma: right, it's a google question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think so. If not, there's always [K9 Mail](http://www.androidtapp.com/k9-mail/) which certainly supports POP3.